# Serialize field of type Type with FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the Net20 library of Json.NET (v90r1) in Unity3D and I'm trying to use Json.NET to serialize a field of type Type.

I've found that `FormatterAssemblyStyle` can affect the automatically generated type information, but it doesn't seem to affect fields that are of type Type. For example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
        };

        Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo(), settings));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public System.Type type = typeof(void);
}
```

This will result in the following JSON string:

```
{
  "$type": "Foo, Assembly-CSharp",
  "type": "System.Void, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
}
```

As you can see, `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` has been used for `$type`, but `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` has been used for `type`.

This is my desired output:

```
{
  "$type": "Foo, Assembly-CSharp",
  "type": "System.Void, mscorlib"
}
```

How do I make both types print the same way? I haven't been able to find an answer because most search results relate to serializing private members or serializing classes *with* type information instead of serializing classes that *contain* types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [sources](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/2e7b24e9b1873a615bbc8ae2302fd3d174cdb9f2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L400):

```
internal static bool TryConvertToString(object value, Type type, out string s)
{
    //...
    type = value as Type;
    if (type != null)
    {
        s = type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        return true;
    }
    //...
}
```

If object type is of `Type` type, it's formatted as [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)

However you can follow [CustomJsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) example to create custom converter for `Type`:

```
public class TypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (typeof(System.Type).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
        {
            // here you decide how much information you really want to dump
            Type type = (Type)value;
            writer.WriteValue(type.FullName + ", " + type.Assembly.GetName().Name);
        }
        else 
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(System.Type).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
        Converters = { new TypeConverter() } 
    };

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo(), settings));
```